# build the application, and an environment variable error occurs when accessing after build

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, prisma, nuxtjs3

I am using Nuxt3 and Prisma to build the application, in the development environment, they run fine, when I execute the `npm run build`command, there is also no output error.nuxt3 outputs the `.output` folder.
[build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1bh1.png)

But when I use the command start to run, prisma prompts me environment variable could not be found.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75OY9.png)

I recreated the `.env` file under the output `.prisma` folder, but it doesn't work.
[recreated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbJMJ.png)

How can I solve the environment variable in production problem?

Comment: In the future, please do not post images of code/errors. Please post the full error in your post body. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

Your `.env` file should be in the same directory as your `schema.prisma` file. I'm not sure what framework/library you are using, but it looks like it emits a `schema.prisma` file within `node_modules`, which is not where your environment variables should go. Wherever you actually have your `schema.prisma` is where the `.env` file should go.

Take a look at the Prisma documentation about environment variables if you need help configuring where it's supposed to go: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/development-environment/environment-variables